# How to access a custom module from the website (for portal users) [odoo13]

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

I have a custom module for user to upload some information and files

I can use forms and make the module accessible from the website but I need them to be able to edit there recored also, exactly like if they are internal user but only for y custom module

anyone knows how to do that thank u very much in advance.

### edit

after reading the comment of @KevalMehta

I think my question should be how to update a record from a form

this is my code to create a new record in my module

```
      request.env['manager.create_company_link'].sudo().create(kw)
```

so first I think I need the id of the record I need to update before how to update it

I thing @KevalMehta is referring to me using `.sudo()` how to give the right access

Comment: Make portal user and give access rights for update for your module records.

Comment: how can I do so, how can he update them do u mean using a form @KevalMehta

Comment: No, you just assign security group of portal user from tha res.partner object to your relevant one and from your custom module allow those user to update.

Comment: sorry but am not following can you please explain